# Регулярка на шарпе находит лишнее

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой текст: 
GET /?code=KYTW/9Bjv7m7OhrXmuZd50PuvRq5b4TVi3GIH5ZXOVl59XQL8yMAhuC2IqS7XIsxSQauZA==&state= HTTP/1.1

Написал регулярку

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"code=(\S*)&state");

MatchesCollections matches = regex.Matches(decodeMessage);
```

И в ответе получается:

> code=KYTW/9Bjv7m7OhrXmuZd50PuvRq5b4TVi3GIH5ZXOVl59XQL8yMAhuC2IqS7XIsxSQauZA==&state

В коллекции только такая строка, других нет. 
Мне нужна строка:
KYTW/9Bjv7m7OhrXmuZd50PuvRq5b4TVi3GIH5ZXOVl59XQL8yMAhuC2IqS7XIsxSQauZA==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вы только матчи нашли, надо дальше писать код. Например так:

```
var decodeMessage = "GET /?code=KYTW/9Bjv7m7OhrXmuZd50PuvRq5b4TVi3GIH5ZXOVl59XQL8yMAhuC2IqS7XIsxSQauZA" +
"==&state= HTTP/1.1";
var regex = new Regex(@"code=(\S*)&state");

var matches = regex.Matches(decodeMessage);
foreach (Match element in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Матчасть: [Конструкции группировки в регулярных выражениях](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions)

Но у меня огромное подозрение, что регулярку тут не нужны и вы из пушки по воробьям стреляете.

У вас входная строка - явно URL и можно просто разбить на пары ключ-значение и найти нужный нам элемент.

Например:

```
var uri = "/?code=KYTW/9Bjv7m7OhrXmuZd50PuvRq5b4TVi3GIH5ZXOVl59XQL8yMAhuC2IqS7XIsxSQauZA" +
"==&state= HTTP/1.1";
Uri myUri = new Uri($"http://localhost{uri}");
var param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("code");
Console.WriteLine(param1);
```

Этот вопрос на en so: https://stackoverflow.com/q/659887/5752652